# Convert multiple documents into one documents in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

document 1:

```
{
_id: abcdef,
name: "foo",
time: [1234],
doc: [1234]
}
```

document 2:

```
{
_id: alexa,
name: "alexa",
time: [1234],
doc: [1234]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
time[1234],
alexa[1234],
foo[1234]
}
```

I have multiple documents in MongoDB, I want to merge the document and make it one document.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sgrsisl0i12) merge multiple documents into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$addFields` convert name and doc as object using `$arrayToObject` in `root` field
- `$group` by mull and merge objects in root using `$mergeObjects`
- `$addFields` time to get union time from array of array using `$reduce` and `$setUnion`
- `$replaceRoot` to replace merged object from root field and time field using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      root: {
        $arrayToObject: [[{ k: "$name", v: "$doc" }]]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $mergeObjects: "$root" },
      time: { $push: "$time" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      time: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$time",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $setUnion: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: ["$root", { time: "$time" }]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6hodbhnc3PQ)